paraValidator session keys requires read permission for non owner
Disclaimer: this topic is about manipulating session keys of a Polkadot validator, these operations are considered very risky for validators, do not try these unless you know 100% what you are doing.
I just noticed that the paraValidator session key requires an extended read permission to back correctly parachains properly, which seems surprising to me.
For reference, other keys like babe require only owner access to produce relay blocks.
Situation in which I noticed that behavior:

Backed up my session keys remotely with owner only accees 600

Restored my validator session keys from remote access, directly in keystore dir of the node using sudo rsync.
rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -r ./keystore {server}:/var/lib/polkadot/chains/polkadot

Chowned the keystore dir to the user/group running the validator service polkadot
-rw------- 1 polkadot polkadot


At this point, the validator was authoring blocks, but missing all parachain votes.
The validator started to cast votes as soon as I set session keys permissions to 644.
I tend to consider this an anomaly, as only the node owner should be required to access the session keys.
Any expert feedback would be appreciated.

If you call rotate_keys, the keystore will automatically store all keys using 600. You should check this again, I think you maybe misinterpreted something.

@bkchr yes correct, I realized that later. I though it came from me because another set of keys was set to 644.
The problem is: on v1.11.0, validator node doesn't back parachains when keys are set to 600, it needs keys to be 644.
